# PHP Show if hides update fields, but they get overwritten with an empty string

Tags: php, mysql

This is one of those ones that probably falls between PHP and SQL stuff.

Basically I have a page where some update fields are displayed depending on who is logged, for example:

```
<?php if ($row_Users['UserID']=="101"){ ?>
    <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_lodges['101_finalist'],"Yes"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="101_finalist"  value="Yes"/>
    <input type="text" class="rankfield" name="101_rank" value="<?php echo($row_lodges['101_rank']); ?>" />
<?php }  ?>
<?php if ($row_Users['UserID']=="102"){ ?>
    <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_lodges['102_finalist'],"Yes"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="102_finalist"  value="Yes"/>
    <input type="text" class="rankfield" name="102_rank" value="<?php echo($row_lodges['102_rank']); ?>" />
<?php }  ?>
```

The issue I have is that if User101 is logged in and updates fields 101_finalist and 101_rank, it overwrites 102_finalist and 102_rank with an empty string.

Is it possible to prevent each user from seeing the other fields for other users, and prevent the existing values for those other users not be overwritten?

Hope that makes sense!

Thank you.

Comment: You need to strip your question down to the basics. I would also remove your second question.

Comment: You might consider cleaning that up and quit breaking tags like that. Makes it much more difficult to read and not pleasing to the eye

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this. It's basically what @taco is saying:

```
<?php
// Set's the default user logged in
$_def   =   ($row_Users['UserID'] == "101")? '101': '102'; ?>
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_lodges[$_def.'_finalist'],"Yes"))) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?> type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $_def; ?>_finalist"  value="Yes"/>
<input type="text" class="rankfield" name="<?php echo $_def; ?>_rank" value="<?php echo ($_def == '101')? $row_lodges['101_rank']:$row_lodges['JA_rank']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<?php 
$userid = $row_Users['UserID'];
$finalist   =   $userid."_finalist";
$rank   =   $userid."_rank";
?>
    <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_lodges[$finalist],"Yes"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="101_finalist"  value="Yes"/>
    <input type="text" class="rankfield" name="101_rank" value="<?php echo($row_lodges[$rank]); ?>" />
```